# How do I run a short code within custom HTML code block on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a plugin to run within a style div setup. For some reason the php function does not call and display the short code

```html
  <div id="vehicle_selector_container">
        <div id="vehicle_selector_boxes">
            <div id="vehicle_selector_header_left">Search for Manufacturer and Model</div>
            <div id="vehicle_selector_list">
                <div id="vehicle_selector_list_left"></div>
                <div id="vehicle_selector_list_right"></div>
                <div id="listbox_vehicle_selector" style="opacity: 1;"><?php echo do_shortcode('[ymm_selector template="horizontal_selector.php"]'); ?></div>
            </div>
            <div id="vehicle_selector_selections">
                <div id="vehicle_selector_manufacturer">
                    <div id="vehicle_selector_manufacturer_header">No Manufacturer selected</div>
                    <div id="cancel_manufacturer" class="vehicle_selector_button_cancel" onclick="clearHeader(0);" style="display: none;"></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <div id="vehicle_selector_manufacturer_thumb"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="vehicle_selector_model">
                    <div id="vehicle_selector_model_header">No Model selected</div>
                    <div id="cancel_model" class="vehicle_selector_button_cancel" onclick="clearHeader(1);" style="display: none;"></div>
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                    <div id="vehicle_selector_model_thumb"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Shaun Barratt. Please inlclude the PHP function you are talking about. Without it we won't be able to help you

Comment: Did you develop the plugin yourself or is it a 3rd party plugin? What do you mean with a "custom HTML code block"? Is this in a file, or is it a block saved in the database? You need to apply the filter `the_content` render the shortcodes.

Comment: The PHP function can be found within the code "<?php echo do_shortcode('[ymm_selector template="horizontal_selector.php"]'); ?>"

Comment: The plugin is a 3rd party plugin. The new WordPress has a stupid page builder editor whereby you add blocks to create content. In this example, I used a custom HTML block

Comment: That php code was provided by the developer. It doesn't work even if I use it on it's own

Comment: If you use the shortcode on it's own without the php code then it works but you cannot do this within html code can you?